# Get the caption of figures to build a personalized list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, journal-publishing, journal

I would like to build a very simple list of figures (as required by [Cambridge Journals](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayMoreInfo?jid=MRF&type=ifc)).
They should be ordered to have a progressive number, thus in order of appearance. First all the figures and then the tables.

The code I am actually using it trivial and repetitive (as again in the Journal example):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{3.6cm}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-1.8cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.8cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.8cm}
\usepackage[pdftex, demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    % 
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{image1.pdf}
        \caption{Caption 1, some words}
        \label{FIG:1}
    \end{figure}
    % 
    % 
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{image2.pdf}
        \caption{Caption 2, some other words}
        \label{FIG:2}
    \end{figure}
    % 
    \newpage
    %
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
    \par\vspace{4mm}\noindent
    {\bf{List of figures and tables}}

    \noindent
    Fig. \ref{FIG:1}. Caption 1, some words

    \noindent
    Fig. \ref{FIG:2}. Caption 2, some other words
\end{document}
```

[image: Page Example]

Is there a way to repeat the caption written in the figure's caption (as: Caption 1, some words) without rewriting or by copy&paste?

Thinking to a different approach, is it possible to simply rewrite the `\listoffigures` to get the same layout?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I edited the example to make it self contained. I hope it is right now. Thanks!

Comment: Up for using a KOMA class? It provides the option `listof=entryprefix`.

Comment: Is the order of figures and tables of importance, or is having all the figure captions first, then all the table captions ok?

Comment: They should be ordered to have a progressive number, thus in order of appearance. First all the figures and then the tables. Regarding the KOMA class, unfortunately I should use the class provided by the journal, so I suppose I can not switch.

Answer (score 2):

You could patch the caption command to do write out the type. But
i think the journal might not be happy about hacks like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}{
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
}{
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{#1 \csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
}{}{}
\newcommand{\listofcaptions}{
    {\noindent\bfseries\Large List of captions}
    \vspace{1em}
    \@starttoc{lof}
    \@starttoc{lot}
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}

\captionof{figure}{some nice caption with a duck}
\captionof{figure}{some nice caption with a cat}
\captionof{table}{some nice caption with a horse}
\captionof{table}{some nice caption with a lion}
\captionof{figure}{some nice caption with an elephant}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\listofcaptions
\end{document}
```

After multiple runs you get the following:

[image]

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. Well, you are right, could be problematic to get it accepted when uploading. I think in the end I will have to do the list of figures (and tables) by hand (as done in the template). I even struggle to edit this hack to get the same layout as in the image I added, unfortunately I am not so expert. Thanks again!